# Is there a way to find the max of a linq count function?

Tags: database, linq, count, max

I'm a beginner with Linq, and I don't know how to store what I've counted and then find the max within a group by function.

```
            var flights = db.Flights.Select(x => x).ToList();

            var airports = from flight in flights
            group flight by flight.PlannedDepairport into flightGroup
            select flightGroup;

            foreach (var airport in airports)
            {
                airports.Count();

                string x = airport.Key;

            }
```

I've tried looking online and adding the max function to the airport function, but I'm not sure how to even begin to format it. If anyone could help, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group by airportId and sort later

```
var query = 
   from flight in db.Flights
   group flight by flight.PlannedDepairport into flightGroup
   select new 
   {
       AirportId = flightGroup.Key,
       Count = flightGroup.Count()
   };

var query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.Count);

var maxAirport = query.FirstOrDefault();
```